# How to place rounded textview with image near to transparent image android?`

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

How to place rounded image with two textview near to below transparent image? I created transparent image with textview but I don't know how to place round image with two textview ie day and date.
How to achieve expected output?

Expected output is :
 [image]

Here is my code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#AAA" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/overlay_margin"
        android:background="#FFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/salogo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#7000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Marathon for organ donation"
                android:textColor="#CCC"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

But I got output as:
 [image]

Comment: how about using framelayouts

Comment: how to use it to achieve expected one?

Answer (score 6):

Create  `circular_bg.xml` in **drawable folder** 
and write..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
<gradient
    android:endColor="#3399FF"
    android:startColor="#3399FF" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1.5dp"
    android:left="1.5dp"
    android:right="1.5dp"
    android:top="1.5dp" />

</shape>
```

now in your xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="2dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="31 sun"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve almost like this with your current layout too... here is one addition to your relative layour a textView with circular shape

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/overlay_margin"
        android:background="#FFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/salogo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#7000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Marathon for organ donation"
                android:textColor="#CCC"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and for circular shape add below code by creating a xml file in your drawable folder with name circle.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <!-- this is for the outline you can remove this stroke or change the color by replacing #FFFFFF with your color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```